# missing Kinetic.Tween method in Kinetic.js Typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, kineticjs

It seems like the current version of the Kinetic.js Typescript file found on CodePlex (http://kineticjstypescript.codeplex.com/) does not have a tween method.  Looking at the definition file there is no mention of tween and when I do

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: outerArc,
                duration: 1,                    
                strokeWidth: 6,                    
            });
```

I am getting the following error: The property 'Tween' does not exist on value of type 'Kinetic'

How would I update the typescript definition file to include the Tween method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose static typing benefit if you do that. Here is a better way that you can build on top of what is already there in the typescript definition:

```
// Define whats missing there 
declare module Kinetic{
    export interface ITweenConfig{
        node?: any;
        duration?: number;
        strokeWidth?: number;
    }
    export class Tween{
        constructor(config: ITweenConfig);
    }
}

// Now continue as planned
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: outerArc,
                duration: 1,                    
                strokeWidth: 6,                    
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I at least got around the issue with the following:

```
var tween = new Kinetic['Tween']({
                node: outerArc,
                duration: 1,
                strokeWidth: 12,
            });
```

Now my typescript compiles and it calls the Tween function directly in the javascript